# Delay before doing postback in javascript

Tags: javascript

The only way I can think to do a postback on a 3 second delay right now is like this.

```
setInterval("__doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', '' )", 3000);
```

The problem I run into is that it posts back every 3 seconds. Is there a better way to do this or a way to clear interval on this? I am using an asp updatepanel control.

Here is my complete javascript code to give you an idea of what I am trying to do:

```
    var delayb4scroll = 1000 //Specify initial delay before marquee starts to scroll on page (2000=2 seconds)
    var marqueespeed = 2 //Specify marquee scroll speed (larger is faster 1-10)
    var pauseAtBottom = 3000 //Pause at the end of the scroll for this many seconds (3000 = 3 seconds)
    var copyspeed = marqueespeed
    var actualheight = ''
    var boolRunOnce = ''

    function pageLoad() {
        initializemarquee();
    }

    function scrollmarquee() {
        if (parseInt(cross_marquee.style.top) - 975 > (actualheight * (-1) + 8)) //if scroller hasn't reached the end of its height
            cross_marquee.style.top = parseInt(cross_marquee.style.top) - copyspeed + "px" //move scroller upwards
        else { //else, scrollbar has reached the bottom, display for 3 seconds then postback
            setInterval("__doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', '' )", 3000);        
        }
    }

    function initializemarquee() {
        cross_marquee = document.getElementById("vmarquee")
        cross_marquee.style.top = 0
        marqueeheight = document.getElementById("marqueecontainer").offsetHeight
        actualheight = cross_marquee.offsetHeight //height of marquee content (much of which is hidden from view)       
        setTimeout('lefttime=setInterval("scrollmarquee()",30)', delayb4scroll)
    }
```

Comment: try setTimeout, its like setInterval but it only runs once

Comment: Side note: do not pass strings to `setTimeout`/`setInterval`; it uses `eval`!  Pass functions: `setInterval(function(){ __doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', '' ); }, 3000);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function() { __doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', '' ); }, 3000);
```

will run only once.

or you can use the return value from setInterval as a reference to your interval thread, which can then be cleared;

```
myInterval = setInterval(function() { __doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', '' ); }, 3000);
//later
clearInterval(myInterval);
```

---

**Edit:** correct, function syntax added as per comments.

Comment: I made the changes, but it appears to be calling the updatepanels method over and over again in debug mode instead of just once.